# Can I export this Figma animation as a gif?

Tags: animation, frontend, css-animations, figma

I have a figma animation, how can I export it as a gif?

https://www.figma.com/file/9TlSnAI8HVoYPchIP4XOCo/Untitled?node-id=1%3A2&t=C99MqY9OBotPTL1X-1

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the Figma community, you will find several plug-ins that export GIFs. The one I use is Export to GIF/Video by Michael Yagudaev and Soheil Hm. Find more here too: https://discord.com/invite/UFPmsptwTr

Comment: Thank you very much, i download the plugin, it worked flawlessly.